# How can I add a new data structure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, data-structures, postgis, r-tree

I created my own R-Tree and I would like to add it to PostgreSQL, I was reading about [PostGis](http://postgis.net/), However I don't kwow exactly How can I do that.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on a Postgres development forum.

Answer (score 1):

R-Tree is implemented in PostgreSQL as GiST index for two-dimensional geometric data types. To add your own implementation you should consider using GiST infrastructure too. Citing the documentation:

> Traditionally, implementing a new index access method meant a lot of difficult work. It was necessary to understand the inner workings of the database, such as the lock manager and Write-Ahead Log. The GiST interface has a high level of abstraction, requiring the access method implementer only to implement the semantics of the data type being accessed. The GiST layer itself takes care of concurrency, logging and searching the tree structure.

So, first read [this chapter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xindex.html) to make sure you understand the concepts of index methods, operator classes and families.
Then, read about [GiST index and its API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/gist.html). There you can find useful examples that will help you.

Also, a lot of helpful information you can find on [development section](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/) of PostgreSQL site.

Any programming questions you may address to PostgreSQL [developer's mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/).